# Importing SAP WSDL with VS17 - Custom tool warning: The following Policy Assertions were not imported/was not handled

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, sap, policy

I am currently trying to import WSDL files that have been delivered to me by a SAP System. I import the files using the Visual Studio 2017 and add them as a service reference.
After importing I get the following warnings:

```
Custom tool warning: The following Policy Assertions were not Imported:
XPath://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-
com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-
style']/wsdl:binding[@name='ZBPCFI_VIV_KOSTENSTELLE']
Assertions:
<sapattahnd:Enabled 
xmlns:sapattahnd='http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/'>..
</sapattahnd:Enabled>

XPath://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-
com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-
style']/wsdl:binding[@name='ZBPCFI_VIV_KOSTENSTELLE']
Assertions:
<sapattahnd:Enabled 
xmlns:sapattahnd='http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/'>..
</sapattahnd:Enabled>
<saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer 

xmlns:saptrnbnd=
'http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/'>..
</saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer>


Warning Custom tool warning: The optional WSDL extension element 
'Policy' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy' was 
not handled.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-
com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-
style']/wsdl:portType[@name='ZBPCFI_WS_VIV_KOSTL']

Warning Custom tool warning: The optional WSDL extension element 
'Policy' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy' was 
not handled.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-
com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-
style']/wsdl:portType[@name='ZBPCFI_WS_VIV_KOSTL']/
wsdl:operation[@name='ZBpcfiFmVivKostl']
```

Had anybody ever similar or even the same problem? If you want to see the WSDL, I can add it later.

I've already created a new SOAP project with soapUI and the WSDL file. The WSDL file was successfully imported.

Comment: In your case I would try to import the same WSDL in a different tool and see if you get more meaningful error messages. soapUI is good for that.

Comment: I've already created a new SOAP project with soapUI and the WSDL file. The WSDL file was successfully imported. I am writing this in my post, so that it is not only in the comments.

Comment: Run a WSI compliance check on the WSDL in SOAP UI. I suspect it fails WSI compliance. SAP is notorious for this from what I have experienced 4-5 years ago it might be different now.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! 
I passed the test and the summy says "Result: passed". But in some points it says "Not Applicable". Here is the result as HTML page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/41h72zqtz6ci2w9/WSIComplianceCheck_SAP_WS.html?dl=0